# Taking javascript .val() and using it in URL for iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, input

I have the following HTML in my website

```
<form id="storyPanel" method="POST" action="<?= BASE_URL ?>/news/update/process/" style="display: none;">
    <h5>Story options</h5>
    <input type="text" id="title">
    <input type="" id="id" >

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="edit">Edit story title</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="delete">Delete story</button>
</form>
<iframe id = "storyPanel2" src="http://localhost/P4/edit/news/<?= $story->id ?>" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

And I have this snippet of javascript that gives me the value that is in the input

```
 if (Number.isInteger(+d.sortBy)) {
    //editSoldierName(d.id, d.item_id);
    console.log('clicked a story');
    $('#storyPanel').fadeIn();
    $('#storyPanel2').fadeIn();

    $('#title').val(d.id);
    $('#id').val(d.sortBy);
}
```

I am still learning how this all works but right now I know that the input has the id of the story I am trying to view.

I want to be able to store its value in a variable and then append it to the end of my url for example:

P4/edit/news/57

Right now I have some re used php that usually gets my story id, but I know its wrong because I can't create a story object outside the iframe and then pass in the id that way. I wanted to know if there was any way to pass in the "id" from javascript into something I can append to the end of the URL. Sorry if this sounds dumb

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are aiming for?

```js
const $input = $("#story-id"), $frame = $("#story-panel-2");

$input.change(e => {
  const value = $input.val();
  $frame.attr('src', `https://placehold.it/${innerWidth}x${value}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>ID: <input id="story-id"></label>
<iframe id="story-panel-2"></iframe>
```

Comment: So I add this before creating the iframe? My script is located at the bottom of my file, does this mean that the const storyFrame would contain my id element? If I add this in my script then how do I retreive the new variable? Sorry I am just confused on how to pass in this variable correctly. To better ask my question: How do I use the storyFrame constant in my html code. Is the scope for it valid and I can just use that variable wherever?

Comment: Sorry just realized what you meant, I am not worried about updating my site, I just need it to load so that way I can access the edit and delete buttons on that specific story. Right now I am having trouble just redirecting to the write page. I am actually not using the form submit for anything.

Comment: @BillTaha, if you want to redirect to a page for editing the item, you can use built in attributes on the `<form>` element. See the following documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form. You can use the `action` attribute on the form in conjunction with the `name` attribute on the input.